# Make a div responsive width/height in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have an image container with an image. The size is 317x242px. I placed the `image-container` inside a `col-md-3` div. The width is a little bit larger in bootstrap, not exactly 317px, but it's not problem, because I'm using `background-size:cover` to fill the whole div.

How is it possible to keep the dimension, if the width smaller/higher than 317px?

http://www.bootply.com/6waABmJhuL

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

I have created a few more classes and used placeholders to give you an idea of the outcome.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/317x242">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image-container">
         <img src="http://www.placehold.it/317x242">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/317x242">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.col-md-3{
  width:30%;
  }
.image-container {
    background:red;
    border: 2px solid red;      
}

img{ width: 100%;
}
```

[Booty of Original code](http://www.bootply.com/2XUVM8fYOD#)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recomand you to use `background-size:cover` to enlarge the image because the quality will decrease and you can clearly see the diference especially on mobile view.

The best way to fix your problem is to use images with bigger dimensions. For example if you image is 317x242px and the block (`col-md-3`) reach 400px, it's best to use images with a 2 times bigger width than the block, for this case 800px (retina view).

So, don't resize images bigger than their actual size because it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I added padding-top:76.34% for my div. Now it keeps the dimension.

(242/317)*100 = 76.34.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class="img-responsive" to the  tag and it will automatically handle whatever image you give it.